# Waiting for ThreadPool to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, streamwriter

I developed an application that saves 10000 lines of lorem ipsum in .txt file on the disk. I used **StreamWriter** to actually write these lines, and **ThreadPool** to distribute the computational process to the available threads/cores.

The saving is very fast, even with 1 million lines, but the problem is, not all lines are saved and the last one is saved **partially**. When I close the program, it writes to file again for some reason.

I have the following string:

```
String loremipsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
```

And the rest of the code is:

```
    private StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("loremipsum.txt");
    private Object lockObject = new Object();

    // Button that initiates the process
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
            {
                SaveFile(writer, loremipsum);
            });
        }
    }

    private void SaveFile(StreamWriter w, String text)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            w.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
```

Since the StreamWriter is not thread-safe, I'm using a locking object.

If I open my .txt file with my program running it has only 9998 lines with the last one being incomplete.

[image]

If I close the program, it rewrites to file again, adding all the lines, but again the last one is incomplete. Why this?

I suppose the lines are saved partially because the ThreadPool's threads need some time to finish their work. Am I correct? If so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you use Flush() and then Close().  The streamwriter like all stream classes buffer the write data and don't actually write to the file until the buffer is full.  Often with streams the last buffer doesn't get written and using Flush() will solve the issue.

Comment: There's no conceivable reason why you'd use multiple threads for this.  There is no CPU bound operation here and you can only write one line at a time.  Just write all 10,000 lines in one thread, and don't forget to dispose of the `StreamWriter` when you're finished.

Comment: @CharlesMager I dont know, but using a ThreadPool to do this results in a very fast operation, I tried to write using just one thread but it takes 10 times longer.

Comment: Then it's likely not doing what you think it is.  Everything would have to synchronise because of your lock, so only one line would be written at a time even using multiple threads.  Plus the overhead.  This should be slower (as well as a bad idea).

Comment: How would you check when it's finished?  Your event handler will return nearly immediately, but you won't know when all your tasks are finished executing.

Comment: @CharlesMager Where should I look at then? No point in doing this in a parallel way?

Comment: I ran this and added some code so I could verify when it's finished - to write 1m lines takes around 2.7-2.8 secs on my PC.  It takes around 1.2 secs if I do this in a single thread.

Comment: @CharlesMager then there's something I don't understand..

Comment: It will likely come down to how you're measuring it - your code will queue 10,000 tasks to run and then return - it is not finished at this point (it may not have even started).  I can assure you there is no advantage to be gained by using multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threadpool is making Background threads to perform the tasks that will stop be aborted if the main thread is aborted. You have to wait for all threads to finish and then Flush the stream. 
As you are missing just last lines, More likely you only have a Flush() issue there,not aborted threads.

I trust you also know that your code is worse than doing the work in a single thread. There is no real parallelism happening there while all the overhead is created.

Comment: Should I flush it inside the lock?

Comment: You can, but will not be efficient. ideally you do your flush after you have finished a batch of writing. flush will enforce a disk access and it is a expensive operation. Doing it there will do 10000 flushes

Comment: Okay, could I use a ManualResetEvent to wait for the threads to finish and then flush and close the StreamWriter?

Comment: Probably, but you may get another error because of limitations on number of MREs you can create. The are scarce OS resources. If the objective is to implement a thread-safe stream writer, I would go back to the drawing board. For example how about having a buffer that threads write to in a producer/consumer pattern and only one thread is writing and then flushing.